# Right-to-left writing in OSX Microsoft Office

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, right-to-left, farsi

I bought a MacBook pro last week and I installed Microsoft Office on it but when I want write Farsi (or Arabic) on it, it shows a seperate one (instead of سلام  it show  س ل ا م ) any one know how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft Office for Mac [does not support](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2008/01/mac-office-2008-still-no-arabichebrew.html) RTL languages.

[Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/) and [Nisus Writer](http://www.nisus.com/) are a few good alternatives, although I'm sure there are others.

Comment: openoffice also support RTL I hope MS will solve this problem soon

Comment: That's true. I revealed my bias by not listing it... I don't like OpenOffice, I find it not very usable.